# Java split generates empty first string

Tags: java, string, split

There is path like this /root/folder1/subfolder1/subfolder2. Using split() method it generates empty first element. How can first empty string be avoided ?

Comment: You need to be more specific. What value did you pass to `split()`

A code fragment would help make your question more specific and easier to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strip the leading `/` before calling `split("/")`.

Use e.g. `replaceFirst("^/", "")` to do that.